# OpenLayers: saving added point to geoserver

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I want to add a point and then with wfs-t save this to db.

I work with Openlayers and GeoServer.

```
saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();

wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
"WFS Vectore",
{
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: "1.1.0",
        srsName: "EPSG:4326",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/iran/wms?service=WFS",
        featureType: "population_utf-8",
        featureNS: "http://iran.kadaster.org",
        geometryName: "geom"
    })
});
```

I add point with two method:

1.

```
wfs.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(
        (Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) - 180),
        (Math.floor(Math.random() * 180) - 90)
    )
)]);
saveStrategy.save();
```

2.

```
var drawFeatureController = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(wfs, OpenLayers.Handler.Point);
```

and then add a point with mouse.

```
saveStrategy.save();
```

the second method work bu the first method dosn't work.

I need first method.

how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you add a point with `new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(wfs, OpenLayers.Handler.Point)`, by default feature state set to "Insert" but when you add a point with `vectorLayer.addFeatures()` command, the feature state is null.

when OpenLayers wants to save change, it see to the state of the feature, and you have to set the added feature state to "Insert"(case-sensitive).